# View components change location after initialization in viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, uitableview, view, viewdidappear

I have a simple screen with a `tableView` and a `searchBar`. It was fine until I used `viewDidAppear`. Now as I use this method, components behaves unexpectedly.
For Example:

- `UISegmentedControll` does not appear untill I swap on screen (I have implemented gestures)
- When I search and then cancel my results, all GUI components are shifted downward.

I am using iOS 7 adjustment:

```
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Here are the screen shots:

[image]

Before I search:

[image]

After I search anything and then cancel search, It goes down like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Auto-Layout, check your layout constrait. If not, set property autoResizingMask to the correct ones.

Comment: So could you please paste your code above? And give us some descriptions about your NIB files too.